# How to make an array of specific values from an array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

When I get results from an API with this function

```js
let recipeArray = async function getRecipeByPreference() {
  try {
    let results = await axios.get('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?number=5&apiKey=*****', {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })

    return recipeArray = results.data.results.slice(0, 5);

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

These are the results returned in recipeArray:

```
0: {id: 716426, title: 'Cauliflower, Brown Rice, and Vegetable Fried Rice', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/716426-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg'}
1: {id: 715594, title: 'Homemade Garlic and Basil French Fries', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/715594-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg'}
2: {id: 715497, title: 'Berry Banana Breakfast Smoothie', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/715497-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg'}
3: {id: 644387, title: 'Garlicky Kale', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/644387-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg'}
4: {id: 716268, title: 'African Chicken Peanut Stew', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/716268-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg'}
```

I want to put the first 5 ID numbers in the recipeArray, so I get this:

```
recipeArray = [716426,715594,715497,644387,716268]
```

and console.log(recipeArray[0]); will give me `716426`

I know there are similar questions here on stack overflow but I can't make the solutions work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just change `results.data.results.slice(0,5);` to `results.data.results.slice(0,5).map(({id})=> id);` and it should work ;)

```js
const results = [{
    id: 716426,
    title: 'Cauliflower, Brown Rice, and Vegetable Fried Rice',
    image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/716426-312x231.jpg',
    imageType: 'jpg'
  },
  {
    id: 715594,
    title: 'Homemade Garlic and Basil French Fries',
    image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/715594-312x231.jpg',
    imageType: 'jpg'
  }, {
    id: 715497,
    title: 'Berry Banana Breakfast Smoothie',
    image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/715497-312x231.jpg',
    imageType: 'jpg'
  }, {
    id: 644387,
    title: 'Garlicky Kale',
    image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/644387-312x231.jpg',
    imageType: 'jpg'
  }, {
    id: 716268,
    title: 'African Chicken Peanut Stew',
    image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/716268-312x231.jpg',
    imageType: 'jpg'
  }
];

const idArray = results.slice(0, 5).map(({
  id
}) => id);

console.log(idArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You could map the Array you got and make it only have the recipe Ids**

```js
return recipeArray = results.data.results.slice(0,5).map(elem => elem.id)
```

[Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an Array method that changes the array to match the function passed, in our case we want to turn every recipe object into just its ID.